# Rails - content_tag for table cell with rowspan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, actionview, actionviewhelper

How would you translate this into a Rails content_tag?

```
<td rowspan="4">glah</td>
```

Comment: I've used the content tag, but how do I specify the rowspan using a content tag helper? Haven't seen an examples pop-up. content_tag(:td, "glah")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
content_tag(:td, "glah", :rowspan => '4')
```

Comment: ahh, makes sense now...similar to passing it a :class =>

Comment: I've just checked out the documentation and I must say it isn't quite clear on that point. They must have assumed it would be obvious, but isn't.